# How to convert known type to pointer to type parameter in a switch?

Tags: go, generics

I'm trying to write a function which converts a byte array of JSON string to another in accordance with the **type parameter** of the return value as the following rule:

- map[string]interface{}: convert to map[string]interface{}
- []byte: no conversion, return as is
- struct: convert to the struc

My code is as follow:

```
func GetJsonData[T any](jsonByteArray []byte) (result *T, err error) {
    var buff T

    switch any(result).(type) { // https://appliedgo.com/blog/a-tip-and-a-trick-when-working-with-generics
    case *[]byte:
        result = &T(jsonByteArray)
    default:
        err = json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &buff)
        result = &buff
    }

    return
}
```

This code occurs following **type error** at the point of **cast** the type of jsonByteArray to T as follows:

```
cannot convert jsonByteArray (variable of type []byte) to type T
```

How can I assign the pointer of this **[]byte** type variable to the generic type return value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `T` is constrained by `any`, you can’t directly convert. You have to *assert* that `&jsonByteArray` is really the same type as `*T` in that switch case:

```
func GetJsonData[T any](jsonByteArray []byte) (result *T, err error) {
    var buff T

    switch any(result).(type) {
    case *[]byte:
        result = any(&jsonByteArray).(*T)
    default:
        err = json.Unmarshal(jsonByteArray, &buff)
        result = &buff
    }

    return
}
```

This makes the compile error go away, however it isn’t particularly good design. If you need to specialize `json.Unmarshal` for only one type (`*[]byte`) you are better off changing the call sites instead of using a generic function.

I assume that your goal is to allow callers to get the byte slice as is, instead of unmarshalling. Then at call site you would call the function as

```
data := GetJsonData[[]byte](jsonByteArray)
```

This means that at that point **you already know** that `jsonByteArray` is a byte slice.

Then, there’s no reason to call the function. You can simply take the address of the argument: `data := &jsonByteArray`, and use `json.Unmarshal` everywhere else.